How to determine the way in which shear stress flows through a particular cross-section?
Is there a specific reason why shear distribution goes directly downward in a rectangular cross-section, while in a circular cross-section, the small shear forces diverge at the top and seem to converge at the bottom?

The average shear stress formula, $\tau_{xy}$, doesn't seem to specify the direction of shear flow since it's assumed to go straight down and a transverse loading applied in the plane of symmetry of the cross-section when deriving the equation:
$$\tau_{xy}=\frac{VQ}{It}$$
How is the direction of shear stress determined for any arbitrary cross-section?
Using this equation, I found that the shear stress distribution in a rectangular cross-section resembles a parabola. However, when I looked it up, I saw that the circular cross-section distribution also looks parabolic. Does this mean the same equation was used to find both distributions, or am I misunderstanding something? I'm completely new to shear stress distribution, so apologies if my questions seem simple or unclear.

When you consider circular pipe section, it makes sense for the shear direction to essentially be tangential, but that is just an intuition.

Hmm.. But do you have an idea on how the shear direction would be for any kind of section?

Maybe you could use a condition that at a fixed vertical coordinate, the axial deflection must be the same for the whole horizontal line or plane. When you look at these horizontal lines starting at the top, they get wider as you go down and if you uniformly divide them into same number of segments and connect the corresponding segments into elements, the non central elements will be skewed to their respective sides. However, I'm not sure if this would lead to the right answer in general.
